# usb_kill_urb, usb_submit_urb, usb_find_interface in a driver showing unknown symbols

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm compiling a kernel driver (I know almost nothing about drivers).

The driver code was written under 2.6 and I'm porting it to 3.5.40.

my `uname -a`: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.3
Linux adam-ros 3.5.0-40-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 23 17:38:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I used the command "sudo insmod ./usbcan.ko" and in "/var/log/kern.log" the information is listed as below:

```
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020492] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_kill_urb (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020513] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_submit_urb (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020540] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_find_interface (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020556] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_put_dev (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020568] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_free_urb (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020584] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_deregister_dev (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020600] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_get_dev (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020612] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_alloc_urb (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020625] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_register_dev (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020638] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_register_driver (err 0)
Sep 25 03:27:58 adam-ros kernel: [11354.020650] usbcan: Unknown symbol usb_deregister (err 0)
```

I wonder whether it's that I did not load the correct driver mod being a dependency or I should link somestuffs in the Makefile?

Thx for answering!

Comment: Try modprobe instead of insmod.  Looks like usb-storage.ko is not loaded.  Also try 'lsmod | grep usb'.  Some of those symbols show up in that driver for me: nm -g /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko

Comment: Still the same problem after loading usb-storage. I do find these symbols in the usb-storage. That's strange, isn't it??

Comment: Wait. usb-storage's nm: usb_kill_urb is 'U' meaning 'Undefined symbol used but not defined. Dependency on another library.' Maybe I'll try some other libraries.

Comment: Are you sure the drivers is compiled with the 3.5 kernel source ?

Comment: Yes. The drivers are compiled with 3.5 kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an stupid thing, but I had exactly the same problem and I changed the Makefile by this new one (there is nothing special....) and it worked.

```
obj-m := usbmodule.o

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions
```

I cleaned first my previous compilations (I did some tests before) and it worked. Maybe the problem was on previous compiled files like usbmodule.o and other files. I can not give you an exactly answer, only advise you to try to clean previous compilation files and compile again using this simply Makefile. Bear in mind your current Linux kernel version that must match with the installed Linux kernel headers. (Check it with uname -a)

I hope it helps you. I know is not to much, but I solved the same issue on this way.

Comment: Thx for the advice. However the project was so long time ago, and I don't know whether I can find the code or not. Anyway, hope it'll help the later guys who might have the same problems as we do.